# XML and XPATH injection attack in Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

How I can validate the XML as message payload to a Spring integration end point for XML injection attack.

Comment: Doesn't `<int-xml:validating-filter>` help you ?

Comment: Hi Artem...if the xml file is a input to a sftp endpoint or any other  ...How can I join this transformer to the end point

Comment: It is just `<filter>`, so you can simply add it as an endpoint in front of others and wire them with channel or wrap to the `<chain>`